# tmux/.tmux.conf: string cut from the left

Tags: console, tmux

This is about configuring the tmux console's status bar by a script stored in `$HOME/.tmux.conf`. The variable `#{pane_current_path}` gives access to the current directory when applying something like

```
set -g status-left "#[fg=black]#{pane_current_path}"
set -g status-left-length 32
```

However, when it gets too long, it is by default cut from the right, i.e.

```
/the/very/long/path/to/the/current/directory/of/the/pane
```

becomes something like

```
/the/very/long/path/to/the/curre
```

It would be nicer to have only the trailing name of the directory, i.e. something like

```
he/current/directory/of/the/pane
```

How can this be setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [formats](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#FORMATS) section of the man page, you can restrict the length of variables, truncating from the left by providing a negative length prefix as in:

```
set -g status-left "#[fg=black]#{=-32:pane_current_path}"
```

I think this is available from version 2.3.