# Tmux truncate pane current path

Tags: bash, tmux

I want to show current pan's path in the window status but as `pan_current_path` returns absolute path then it can be very large. So the question is how to truncate it like this:

```
PWD = /Users/SomeUser/SomeFolder/SomeFolder2/SomeFolder3
OUTPUT = .../SomeFolder2/SomeFolder3
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54170679/14186145) we can truncate it from the end to specific length but it will be like

```
OUTPUT = lder/SomeFolder2/SomeFolder3
```

So how to change remaining part of the folder name to "..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end I simply wrote the bash script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
path="$1"
fixed_length=$2
if (( ${#path} > $fixed_length )); then
    path=$(echo "$path" | tail -c "$fixed_length")
    if ! [[ "$path" =~ ^//* ]]; then
        path="/${path#*/}"
    fi
    path="...$path"
fi
echo $path
```

Usage (where 64 is the fixed length):

```
#(~/.tmux/scripts/truncate_path.sh #{pane_current_path} 64)
```